# gtest - undefined reference to `testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)'

Tags: c++, makefile, googletest

I'm trying to create makefile and compile simple example of `gtest` but I get the error:

> g++ main.o  -o exampleOutput main.o: In function `main':
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to`
>   testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)' collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status make: *** [output] Error 1

This the main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << "This is test" << endl;
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the makefile:

```
INCLUDE = -I/usr/include/
LIBPATH = -L/usr/lib/

output: main.o 
    g++ main.o  -o exampleOutput

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp $(INCLUDE)  $(LIBPATH) -lgtest -lgtest_main  -pthread
```

The header files (of Gtest) are located in `/usr/include/gtest`
and the lib files are located in `/usr/lib`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: First, do it on the commandline without Make. It takes 3 short commands. 1) Compile `main.o` 2) Link it
together with your libraries, outputting `exampleOutput`. 3) Run the program to
see it's right.  This will reveal all the mistakes
(and that they are unrelated to Make). Then put it into your Makefile.

Comment: Hi, I already tried it. this is the command: `c++ main.cpp -L/usr/lib/ -lgtest -lgtest_main -pthread` and it created `a.out` file and I ran it. it seems to work well

Comment: Hi. Yes, but you need know how to 1) Compile `main.o` 2) Link it
together with your libaries, outputting `exampleOutput`. Your difficulty
is not about C++, or googletest, or Make. It is just not knowing how
to (compile 1 or more object files) and then (link them together with some libraries into
a program). This is elementary knowledge for any programming with
compiled languages. Here is [a good book](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/)
and sections 2.3 through 2.8 will help immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-lgtest` and `-lgtest_main` arguments should be passed when linking exampleOutput, not when compiling main.o. The reason it works with the command in your comment is that that command is doing both steps in one go, whereas your makefile is not.

The makefile is also incorrect in that the target is named only `output` whereas the command actually produces `exampleOutput`, so this command will always be executed even when it is not needed, because the file named `output` that it is expecting will never actually be produced...